# How to declare a function pointer to a template function whose return type is dependent on template class

Tags: c++, c++11

Title might sound confusing but here is some code which will clear it,

```
template<class Act>
auto ActWrapper(Act && act, std::mutex mutex) -> decltype(act())
{
    //....
    return act();
}
```

How to write a function pointer to above function?

Comment: The above isn't a function, it's a function template capable of generating functions.

Comment: Since `std::mutex` doesn’t have a copy constructor, is this possible to call in a useful way?

Answer (score 4):

There are no template function pointers, if that is what you were looking for. You need to know exactly the signature of the function instantiation if you want to have a function pointer to a particular instantiation.

You can always cheat with `auto`:

```
auto ptr = &ActWrapper<foo>;
```

If you can't use `auto`, you will need to know the return type:

```
return_t(*ptr)(foo&&, std::mutex) = &ActWrapper<foo>;
// or
decltype(ActWrapper(std::declval<foo>(), {}))(*ptr)(foo&&, std::mutex) = &ActWrapper<foo>;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to write a function pointer to above function?

You cannot declare a function pointer to a function template. You can only declare a function pointer to a function.

If `Foo` is valid type for `ActWrapper`, you may declare a function pointer to `ActWrapper<Foo>`. At that time you would know the return type of the function and you can use it.

```
using returntype = <the return type of Foo::operator()>;
using FuncionPtrType = returntype (*)(Foo&&, std::mutex);
FuncionPtrType functionPtr = ActWrapper<Foo>;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46160642/27302), you cannot make a simple function pointer to the entire set of functions, only to a particular instantiation of the template.

If you need something you can pass around to refer to the whole set and not a specific function, you need to wrap it in a lambda or a class with `operator()`, and pass that around instead.